# AVR in system programming (ISP)

Tags: avr, programmer, isp

Can I use [this programmer](http://www.circuitvalley.com/2011/04/avr-serial-port-programmer.html) to program an onboard Atmega168 TQFP chip?

[image]

Does the board have to be powered up or the programmer supplies it's own +5v?

Here's what the programmer's schematic looks like.

[image]

Comment: Don't know about the rest, but it seems that the board must be powered up; the programmer doesn't supply it's own 5V.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to power the board. The +5V connection shown on the connector comes from your board and is used as a pull-up for the reset signal: the 10k\$\Omega\$ resistor keeps reset high until it is pulled to a low level by the transistor.

The latest PCs are often no longer supplied with an EIA-232 interface. In that case [this programmer](http://www.ladyada.net/make/usbtinyisp/) may be an alternative.

Comment: The USBtinyISP is a great programmer. Found it more reliable than Atmel ones.

Answer (score 0):

USBASP is the best programmer and is very fast as compared to Serial ISP Programmer. I recommend you to use this one. Specially for big size Flash Microcontrollers.

Here is the link of [USBasp](http://www.fischl.de/usbasp/)